# DRF Allow AnonymousUser owner with HyperlinkedModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When the book owner is authenticated it's ok, but if the book owner is not authenticated this error appears `ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000002677F18EE00>": "Book.owner" must be an instance of " CustomUser".`. I think this problem is caused by `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`. The `owner` of the book is specified in the `perform_create()` method, which is taken from `self.request.user`. I want authenticated users or non-authenticated users to be able to create books.

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True, # allow Anonymous user
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="books",
    )
    title = models.TextField()
```

serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner_username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="owner.username")

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            "url",
            "owner",
            "owner_username",
            "title",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("owner",)
```

views.py

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

I need your help to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AnonymousUser` is a different model, instead of using that, you can check `request.user.is_authenticated` and if it's `False`, set `owner=None`

Here's an example:

```py
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user if self.request.user.is_authenticated else None
        serializer.save(owner=user)
```